# RegEx no whitespace in third column of mobile number

Tags: regex, numbers

I came up with following regex for a mobile phone number:

```
^\+([0-9]{1,} )+([0-9]{2,} )+[0-9]+
```

Example of valid number:

> +385 552 8221520

What would be the according regex, so I don't get a match if any whitespace in the third capturing group is found:

> +385 552 82215 20 (gives a match now, but not fine!)

Comment: Probably you want [`^\+[0-9]+ +[0-9]{2,} +[0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/A7Gg7C/1). If spaces are optional, replace " +" with " *".

Comment: Hi you two, thanks for the fast comments! The one of Wiktor seems to work fine for my needs. The one of you anubhava doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern contains quantified groupings. The `^\+([0-9]{1,} )+([0-9]{2,} )+[0-9]+` pattern matches a string that starts with `+`, then contains 1 or more repetitons of 1+ digits followed with a space, then 1+ repetitions of 2+ digits followed with a space and then 1+ digits. Thus, it matches many space separated digit chunks. Also, it is not anchored at the end of the string with `$` and might match strings that contain rubbish at the end if used with a regex method that allows partial matches.

To limit to just three space separated digit chunks, you may use any of the following:

- `^\+[0-9]+ +[0-9]{2,} +[0-9]+$` - if there can be 1 or more spaces between the digit groups
- `^\+[0-9]+ ?[0-9]{2,} ?[0-9]+$` - if there can be 1 or 0 spaces between digit groups
- `^\+[0-9]+ *[0-9]{2,} *[0-9]+$` - if there can be 0 or more spaces between digit groups.

Note that `$` added at the end of each pattern. Also, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A7Gg7C/1).